# Ec2 Instance Connect not connecting when using my own IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

When I configure the security group with ssh protocol, port range 22 and I select MyIP, which is using my IP as I checked, the Ec2 Instance Connect does not work.

Anyone else has experienced this?
What is the work around? Having a static Ip address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

When doing a "normal" SSH connection from your own computer to an Amazon EC2 instance, the connection goes **directly from your computer to the EC2 instance**. Thus, the Security Group needs to permit the Inbound connection from the public IP address associated with your computer.

However, when using **EC2 Instance Connect**, an HTTPS connection is established **between your computer and the EC2 Instance Connect Service inside AWS**. That Service then establishes an SSH connection to the EC2 instance. Thus, the connection comes from the Service, rather than your own computer.

Therefore, the Security Group should **permit inbound connections from the IP address range of the EC2 Instance Connect Service**.

You can obtain these addresses from:

- [AWS IP address ranges - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download)
- Search for `EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT`
- Select the range for your applicable **region**

Comment: That's a great explanation. I did think that since I have an interface between my computer and the Ec2, the interface might have it's own IP range. Great pointer to resource, thank you!